# Product Filter in BigCommerce using core PHP

Tags: bigcommerce

I have standard plan of Big Commerce store.
I have to integrate product filter dropdowns in my store. So which is the best way to achieve this functionality.

Kindly suggest

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options:

1.) Upgrade to a Pro or Enterprise plan, and activate product filtering.

2.) Install a product filtering app and configure.

3.) Make a purely JavaScript solution where you hit different product list pages and append results to the current page.

4.) Make a standalone PHP app (or other BC API supported language) and use JS to hit and display the filtered products on your page.

Options 1 & 2 require no code. Options 3 & 4 could take lots of hours to implement. It depends what your budget is, and the requirements of your project.

Comment: Thanks for your reply